# Obtain a FeatureLayer's default renderer in ArcGIS JS SDK?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology

When creating a new FeatureLayer in the ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript, it's possible to specify a [renderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#renderer), to tell the layer how draw on the map.

If you don't specify a renderer, the symbology properties from the layer's REST endpoint are used.

For example, in this [sample States layer](https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/2) the renderer is shown as below, and this is used to symbolise the layer in the absence of the `renderer` property being used in the FeatureLayer constructor:

```
drawingInfo": {
  "renderer": {
    "type": "simple",
    "symbol": {
      "type": "esriSFS",
      "style": "esriSFSSolid",
      "color": ...
```

But when a FeatureLayer is made from this States layer, the `FeatureLayer.renderer` property is `undefined`, as shown in the demo at https://codepen.io/slead/pen/NWLOGWN

```
const featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
  url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/2"
});
console.log("renderer", featureLayer.renderer)
```

How can I obtain the details of the layer's default renderer, being that set by its REST endpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wait for `featureLayer` to be created to get renderer.

Relevant code could then look something like this:

```
featureLayer.on("layerview-create", function(event){
  console.log("renderer", featureLayer.renderer);
});
```